# Transforming object of objects into single object

Tags: javascript, object

I need this kind of format:

```
{ 0: 'apples', 1: 'oranges', 2: 'lemons' }
```

I used to have an array without keys, but, after applying `Object.assign` I currently have this kind of format:

```
{ 0: {code: "apples"}, 1: {code: "oranges"}, 2: {code: "lemons"} }
```

I would appreciate any advise on how to transform it into the first format.

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Do you really have a non-array object with those numeric property names? Do you really want one as a result as well? Or is it really an array, and you want an array?

Comment: I have a non-array object and want a single object as a result. Nina Scholz already answered me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recombine the object by taking out `code`.

This approach uses (upcoming) [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
var object = { 0: { code: "apples" }, 1: { code: "oranges" }, 2: { code: "lemons" } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).map(([key, { code }]) => [key, code]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let o = { 0: {code: "apples"}, 1: {code: "oranges"}, 2: {code: "lemons"} };
let oNew = {};
for (let prop in o) { 
   oNew[prop] = o[prop].code;
}
console.log(oNew);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try  this

```js
const data = { 0: 'apples', 1: 'oranges', 2: 'lemons' }
const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, ele, i)=>({...acc, [i]: {code: data[i]}}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

From `array` to `object` with `reduce`:

```js
console.log(['apples', 'oranges',  'lemons' ].reduce((p,c,i)=>({...p, [i]:c}), {}))
```